# CSS not reloading even though I have a unique link for every load

Tags: php, css, wordpress

First-time web-developer here. I have a wordpress site. I just launched it. I am trying to make some last minute changes to the stylesheet. I have checked and rechecked that the stylesheet has indeed updated on the server.

The webpage is not updating the styling...

I have tried: 
1) doing a hard refresh on the browswer
2) closing the browser window and going to the site again
3) adding a unique string at the end of each stylesheet link like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style1.css?'?><?php echo time() ?>" />
```

When I try updating php files on the server, the update shows up in my browser immediately. However, the stylesheet is still not showing up, why?

the stylesheet name in the chrome developer is different than mine on the server...
It looks like W.style.css,qve...JSOIE45S_4.css

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the href in your parsed-source contain the random time-number?

Comment: Do you have any WP Optimizing plugins installed? often they cache the sytlesheet and cause you massive headaches during development! Disable any plugins you think may cause the issue, and refresh.. then you can diagnose what is causing the issue

Comment: I don't think it is the plugins. I think it probably has to do with my stylesheet being renamed. Why does it get renamed to to those long names?

Comment: @stUrb Yes, it does.

Comment: OK, the issue is definitely these renamed stylesheets. They are overriding my regular ones. What are these renamed stylesheets and how do I get to them?

Comment: they are pagespeed style sheets. How do I get them to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style1.css?'.time() ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify in the source code that the time-appendix actually changed? Probably n Wordpress-internal caching system is active.

If I have problems with the cache, I use an 'incognito window' of the browser.

Comment: verified. Incognito window is not helping. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

sure is better using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style1.css?'.time() ?>" />
```

But I can't understand what does it mean: `/style1.css?'.time()`.

The PHP time() function will return a number like this: 1412004693

so the final results will be: `.../style1.css?1412004693`

If you are going to pass any parameter in GET to /style1.css page you should do like this (give a name to parameter): `.../style1.css?time=1412004693`

so in final try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style1.css?time='.time() ?>" />
```

Hope it can help you!
Bye

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I believe the objective is not to actually use the time stamp by obtaining it from a GET. Rather, it is to force the server to retrieve the css anew, instead of just looking to a cache.